# Signature Inheritance for **kwarg in constructor in python

Tags: python

I have two TypeDict defined as follows:

```py
class TypeFilter1(TypedDict):
    c: str
    d: float

class TypeFilter2(TypedDict):
    e: float
    f: int
```

that I would like to use as types to construct two classes

```py
class MyClass1():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs:Unpack[TypeFilter1]) -> None:
        self.filters = [f"{key}:{values}" for key, values in kwargs.items() if key in TypeFilter1.__annotations__ ]
        self.params = ' '.join(self.filters)
       
class MyClass2():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs:Unpack[TypeFilter2]) -> None:
        self.filters = [f"{key}:{values}" for key, values in kwargs.items() if key in TypeFilter2.__annotations__ ]
        self.params = ' '.join(self.filters)
```

The role of the constructors is to parse `**kwargs` to format a `str` containing only those `kwargs.items()` there are members of their respective `TypeFilterX.__annotations__`:

A use case could be:

```py
a = MyClass1(c="hello", d=2.0) # self.params -> "c:hello d:2.0
b = MyClass2(e=2.1, g=3) # self.params -> "e:2.1"
```

Since both classes do the same thing, I thought that they could inherit the constructor from a `BaseClass` but I wouldn't know how to implement `BaseClass` so that it could parse `**kwargs` using different `TypeFilters`.

I tried to

- create a `GenericTypeFilter` as a parent of both `TyperFilterX` and sign the `super().__init__(**kwargs)` as `self, **kwargs:Unpack[GenericTypeFilter]`, but both classes return an empty `str`
- define `**kwargs:Unpack[T]` in `super().__init__(**kwargs)` where `T = TypeVar("T", TypeFilter1,TypeFilter2)`, but `'TypeVar' object has no attribute
- use `Any`. Same problem as above.

How should I do it? Moreover: now I have **2** `TypeFilterX`, but how would you handle the situation if I have **N** of them?

Thank you!

Comment: Are the `TypedDict`s used for anything other than the `__init__` methods? Does `__init__` do anything with the arguments *except* populate `filters` and `params`?

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the filtering of kwargs from the attribute creation. This enables to inherit from a base-class and then overwrite the filtering. Because in your example, the filtering is almost the same, but only the reference for the filtering (TypeFilterX.**annotation**) changes, even the filtering method can be inherited, e.g.:

```
from typing import TypedDict, Union, Unpack

class TypeFilter1(TypedDict):
    c: str
    d: float

class TypeFilter2(TypedDict):
    e: float
    f: int


class Baseclass():

    INITIALIZER = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs:Union[Unpack[TypeFilter1], Unpack[TypeFilter2]]) -> None:
        filtered_kwargs = self.check_entries(kwargs)
        self.filters = [f"{key}:{values}" for key, values in filtered_kwargs.items()]
        self.params = ' '.join(self.filters)

    def check_entries(self, kwargs: dict):
        filtered_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            if key not in self.INITIALIZER:
                del filtered_kwargs[key]
        return filtered_kwargs

class MyClass1(Baseclass):
    INITIALIZER = TypeFilter1.__annotations__

class MyClass2(Baseclass):
    INITIALIZER = TypeFilter2.__annotations__
```

Comment: The base class probably shouldn't even care too much about the types of arguments passed to it. (I *definitely* wouldn't hard-code references to child-class specific information.) As written, `MyClass1` can still legally accept arguments intended for `MyClass2` and vice versa. You've basically replaced static type checking with runtime type checking.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, though without knowing where else your `TypedDict`s are used, throwing them out may be a non-starter. The base class doesn't *care* about the arguments passed to `_make_filter`; it's the child class's job to ensure only appropriate arguments for itself get passed.

```
class Base:
    # Not Base's job to enforce type safety for the children.
    def _make_filters(self, **kwargs):
        self.filters = [f"{key}:{values}" for key, values in kwargs().items()]
        self.params = ' '.join(self.filters)


class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self, c: str, d: float) -> None:
        self._make_filters(c=c, d=d)

       
class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self, e: float, f: int) -> None:
        self._make_filters(e=e, f=f)
```

The reason I am not defining `Base.__init__` to call `_make_filters` is that, if you want to support multiple inheritance, `kwargs` should be reserved for passing unrecognized arguments up the chain of `super().__init__` calls.

A similar approach using dataclasses, where fields are listed explicitly and `__post_init__` replaces `_make_filter`. (`__post_init__` implements the logic where the above required explicit calls to `_make_filter`). Depending on your use case, `c` et all should, perhaps, be `InitVar`s instead of real fields.

```
@dataclass
class Base:
    filters: dict[str, str] = field(init=false)
    params: str = field(init=false)

    def __post_init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.filters = ...
        self.params = ...


@dataclass
class MyClass1(Base):
    c: str
    d: float


@dataclass
class MyClass2(Base):
   e: float
   f: int
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually combining both answers I managed to find a solution that fits my needs.

@chepner says:

> The base class probably shouldn't even care too much about the types of arguments passed to it.

And this actually convinced me to use `Any` as type for `**kwargs` in `BaseClass`

then @JKupzig says:

> I would separate the filtering of kwargs from the attribute creation. This enables to inherit from a base-class and then overwrite the filtering

Which is somehow the solution, but implementing `**kwargs:Any` allowed me to just borrow the `INITIALIZER = []` class variable.

Hence my implementation became

```py
class Baseclass():

    _parameters_list:dict[str,Any] = {}
    def __init__(self, **kwargs:Any) -> None:
        self._filters:list[str] = []
        for key,values in kwargs.items():
            if key in self._parameters_list:
                if isinstance(values,list):
                    for value in values: # type: ignore
                        self._filters.append(f"{key}:{value}")
                else:
                    self._filters.append(f"{key}:{values}")
            else:
                raise Exception(...)
        

class MyClass1(Baseclass):
    _parameters_list = TypeFilter1.__annotations__

class MyClass2(Baseclass):
    _parameters_list = TypeFilter2.__annotations__
```

Thank you both very much!